# Group Theory: Orders of Elements

Tags: group-theory

Have been given following problem. Let G be group and x $\in G$. Prove that $x^2 = e$ if and only if x is of order one or two. My response. If order of x is 1, then by definition of order of an element, x = e, i.e. x.e = e.e =e, i.e. x.x = e, i.e. $x^2 = e$. Same idea for x having order two, i.e. $x^2 = e$. Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed, more generally $x^k=e$ if and only if the order of $x$ divides $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Your exposition could be simpler. If $x$ has order $1$, then $x = x^1 = e$ so $x^2 = e^2 = e$. If $x$ has order $2$, $x^2 = e$. Both of these follow from the definition of order.

You also forgot the converse: if $x^2 = e$ then the order of $x$, being the least positive integer $n$ such that $x^n = e$, is at most $2$. That is, $1 \le n \le 2$. So $n = 1$ or $n = 2$.

Comment: Thank you Unit. Fully appreciate your response. I initially thought that the logic was more complicated (since I'm new to Group Theory)